# SWRevealViewController - Adding GestureRecognizer to view stops UITableViewCell to work

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uigesturerecognizer

I use SWRevealViewController in my project and it works well except when I add the gesture recognizer to the view. This results in my UITableViewCell not to recognize swipes anymore. When I add the recognizer to e.g. the navigationcontrollers bar it works, but this is not a proper work around.

```
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:self.revealViewController.panGestureRecognizer];
```

Perhaps I missed something?

Comment: Hi! I have the same problem, the UITabaleViewCell can't received the Tap Gesture. How do you resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend adding the gesture to self.navigationController.view.

Comment: Thank you, but same effect. Swipe works fine for the view but swipe (right to left) in the UITableViewCell does not...